# Laravel RESTful Controller routing

Tags: routes, laravel-4

I'm trying to access my URL at:

> www.mysite.com/user/dash/sales

I have in my controllers directory, a DashboardController.php file:

```
<?php

class DashboardController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->beforeFilter('auth');

    }

    /**
     * Supplier's dashboard screen
     *
     */
    public function getSupplier()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.dashboard.supplier');
    }

    /**
     * Sales dashboard screen
     *
     */
    public function getSales()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.dashboard.sales');
    }

    /**
     * Admin's dashboard screen
     *
     */
    public function getAdmin()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.dashboard.admin');
    }

}
```

I've tried all the following possibilities in my routes.php file with no luck:

```
Route::any('user/dash/(:any)', array('uses' => 'DashboardController') );

Route::controller( 'user/dash', 'DashboardController' );

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'before' => 'auth'), function() 
{ 
    Route::controller('dash', 'DashboardController');
});
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions? I'm not quite sure on how to make this a successful route. The error message I get with all those routes is this:

> Controller method not found.

Answer (score 3):

Ok after a lot more digging around and reading loads of articles, there is this rule called "first in, first out":

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

/** RESTful Controllers **/
Route::controller( 'user/dash', 'DashboardController' );
Route::controller( 'user', 'UserController' );
Route::controller( 'product', 'ProductController' );

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'dash', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('product', 'Dash_ProductController');
    Route::controller('user', 'Dash_UserController');
});

/** Home/Fallback Controller **/
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

So therefore if you have a route leading to user, but then want to go deeper, you have to put the deepest FIRST in your routes.php file!

Fantastic article read : [http://laravel.io/topic/30/routes-first-in-first-out](http://web.archive.org/web/20130912011338/http://laravel.io/topic/30/routes-first-in-first-out)

Answered By: user3130415

Comment: @kJamesy Here is the link from the archive, http://web.archive.org/web/20130912011338/http://laravel.io/topic/30/routes-first-in-first-out